# using glob with php mvc results in empty array

Tags: php

I am just trying to print_r the jpg files in a directory like this:

URLROOT is defined as just my path e.g.:

http://localhost:8888/mysite/

```
public function test()
    {

        $imgs = (glob(URLROOT . '/img/*.jpg'));

        print_r($imgs);

        $this->view('pages/test');
    }
```

The view just shows me :

Array ( )

How can I fix this?

Comment: Do you know that you don't have `http://localhost:8888/mysite/` directory? Maybe you need `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`?

Comment: Do you understand that `glob` searches in a __filesystem__?

Comment: @u_mulder, I use URLROOT for normal images and it works fine i.e.: `<img src="<?php echo URLROOT; ?>/img/walk.jpg">`

Comment: @u_mulder, yes. I want to show all the files with .jpg extension in the img folder. I am wanting to show all images as thumbnails but for now I just wanted to print_r the names.

Comment: Your filesystem does not have the path `http://localhost:8888/mysite/img/`. You don't have a folder `http`, `localhost:8888`. Instead you have path like `/var/www/html/mysites` or similar.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand. But then how do I point to the img folder?

Comment: Check your `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, or maybe you have some other constants that point to __root folder ot your site__.

Comment: That gives me: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs

Comment: And if you provide this path to `glob` - what do you see?

Comment: @u_mulder I am confused now because if I print_r it then it works and shows me all the image names. But if I try to display the images I get 'not found' errors with an incorrect path: `http://localhost:8888/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/public‌​/img/blog-masonry-3.‌​jpg`

Comment: So you need to make the path correct.

Comment: @u_mulder, I wish I could! I can't seem to remove the Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ bit which is what I need to remove. `$files = (glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/mysite/public/img/*.jpg'));`

Comment: Use `substr` for example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160535/discussion-between-user8463989-and-u-mulder).